# Problema ao utilizar a função .join()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Qual o problema nesse meu código, eu usei a função .split() para separar a string quando encontra ' ; ' , após separar eu queria juntar de voltar colocando espaços então usei o .join(), porém não vi efeitos vejam:

```
#Irá separar cada palavra quando encontrar o delimitador ';'

reg = str(input('Nome; endereço; telefone: '))

nome, endereco, telefone = reg.split(';')
print('{}  {}  {} '.format(nome, endereco, telefone))

' '.join(reg)
print(reg)

'''
Tentei fazer dessa forma também:

' '.join(nome, endereco, telefone)
print(reg)

n deu.
'''
```

[image: Resultado:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Join faz o que vc está querendo, mas em uma lista:

```
' '.join(['nome', 'endereco', 'telefone'])
'nome endereco telefone'
```

Mas se voce, no exemplo, quer apenas retirar o ponto e vírgura da string original, use o replace, veja o exemplo:

```
reg = 'Carlos; Av. Marechal, 3; 392-323'
reg = reg.replace(';','')

print(reg)
Carlos Av. Marechal, 3 392-323
```

Comment: Obrigado mano, era isso mesmo entendi o .join(), tava lendo na internet também e eu esqueci de atribuir que estava usando a função .slit() logo a frase em si nem sofreu alterações ai sim consegui: https://repl.it/Juvb/3    - mas obrigado voce me ensinou esquema da lista também!